# Markov chains and functions

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $X_t\in S$ be a Markov Chain. Does there exist a function $f\colon S\to S$ such that $X_{t+1}=f(X_t)$?

One way I came up with representing $X_t$ in terms of $X_t$ is 
$$
X_{t+1} = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{, with probability $p_{00}$ if $X_t = 0$} \\
0 & \text{, with probability $p_{01}$ if $X_t = 1$} \\
1 & \text{, with probability $p_{10}$ if $X_t = 0$} \\
1 & \text{, with probability $p_{11}$ if $X_t = 1$} \\
\end{cases}
$$ 
but this this is not a function since $f(0)$ maps both to $0$ and $1$.

Comment: are you looking for a deterministic function $f(\cdot)$?

Comment: I mean a function like in the following example: $A=f(B,C)=B+C$, where $B$ and $C$ are random variables. Can you elaborate on what you mean with a deterministic function.

Comment: I don't think you can find such a deterministic function with random argument as in the example you provided. There is no fixed function (even with random argument) that would describe $X_{t+1}$ using only $X_t$.
However, I think it would be useful for you to check out Martingales (see, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)).

Comment: Thanks you. Could you elaborate on what a non-deterministic function refers to?

Comment: I mean that a random variable $X_{n+1} ~|~ X_n$ is still random. You cannot get the value of $X_{n+1}$ with probability $1$ even if you observe $X_n$.